# PHP action form embed in HTML

Tags: php, html

My form action page is PHP but I want to echo a clickable link and I think PHP doesn´t support this. I've embed this PHP code in HTML tags  but it echos the tags in the page.

Code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

include 'connect.php';

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "sql") {
    echo "Sorry, only SQL files are allowed.\n";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.\n";
        $sqlfile = fopen($target_file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $contents = file($target_file);
        foreach($contents as $line) {
            $result = mysql_query($line) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            $file_name= str_replace("'", "", basename($target_file,".sql"));


        }


        echo "The new data was inserted in database.\n";
        echo "View your data in http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user=$file_name";
        fclose($sqlfile);

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}


?>
```

The problem is here:

```
echo "View your data in http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user=$file_name";
```

How can I make this link clickable?

Thanks!

Comment: Add an A tag around it?

Comment: echo "View your data in <a href='http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user=$file_name' >here </a>";

Comment: I didn't understand that part where the html tags are printed though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question seems to have answered itself. All you have to do is just wrap the link in an Anchor Tag like so

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

    include 'connect.php';

    $target_dir    = "uploads/";
    $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk      = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "sql") {
        echo "Sorry, only SQL files are allowed.\n";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Your file was not uploaded.";
       // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.\n";
        $sqlfile = fopen($target_file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $contents = file($target_file);
    foreach($contents as $line) {
        $result = mysql_query($line) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        $file_name= str_replace("'", "", basename($target_file,".sql"));
    }


    echo "The new data was inserted in database.\n";
    //THIS IS THE ONLY PLACE YOU NEED TO ADDRESS: WRAP URL IN <A> TAGS:
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user={$file_name}' class='view-data-link'>View your data</a>";
    fclose($sqlfile);

} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Check your headers:

You have

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

`application/json` headers cannot return `HTML`. They will return a `JSON` string. In JSON the tags will be returned as they are, they won't be rendered.

You need:

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And then, when you wish to display the link enclose the link in an `A` tag:

```
echo 'View your data in <a href="http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user='.$file_name.'">http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user='.$file_name.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php
```

header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

```
include 'connect.php';

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "sql") {
    echo "Sorry, only SQL files are allowed.\n";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.\n";
        $sqlfile = fopen($target_file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $contents = file($target_file);
        foreach($contents as $line) {
            $result = mysql_query($line) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
            $file_name= str_replace("'", "", basename($target_file,".sql"));


        }


        echo "The new data was inserted in database.\n";
        echo '<a href="http://localhost/public_html/PAD/index.php?user=$file_name">View your data in </a>';
        fclose($sqlfile);

    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}


?>
```